# Extjs 3.3.1 FieldSet with layout fit and grid in it does not resize the grid on window resize

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

```
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
      columns: [ columns here...]
})

var grid = new Ext.Ext.grid.GridPanel({
   store: store,
   loadMask: true,
   autoExpandColumn: 'itemDescription',
   stripeRows: true,
   colModel: colModel
})

var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
   labelWidth: 150,
   bodyStyle: 'padding:2px 5px;',
   autoScroll: true,
   items:[
     new Ext.form.FieldSet({
       layout: 'fit',
       collapsible: true,
       height:300,
       items: [
            grid 
       ]
     }
   ]
})
```

The grid does not change its width once the window gets resized...
Any thoughts???

Comment: It would help to know the entire container structure and not only that the `Grid` is placed inside a `FieldSet` which again is inside a `FormPanel`. Are you sure its not the `FieldSet` which is not resizing? If you put `anchor: '-0'` on the `FieldSet`, does that help?

Comment: you can write it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Grid` will resize according to the `FieldSet` due to `layout: 'fit'`. Since the `FormPanel` doesn't have a layout set, it automatically uses `layout: 'form'`. The `FieldSet` will act as a *normal* `Form Field` and thus needs to be configured to resize it self. This can be done using the `anchor` property of the `FormLayout`:

```
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 150,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:2px 5px;',
    autoScroll: true,
    items:[
        new Ext.form.FieldSet({
            layout: 'fit',
            anchor: '-0',
            collapsible: true,
            height:300,
            items: [
                grid 
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

This will tell the `FieldSet` to always stay 0 pixels from the right edge of the `FormPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

try this.....

```
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
  columns: [ columns here...]
})

var grid = new Ext.Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store: store,
loadMask: true, 
autoExpandColumn: 'itemDescription',
stripeRows: true,
colModel: colModel
})

var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
labelWidth: 150,
bodyStyle: 'padding:2px 5px;',
autoScroll: true,
items : {
   xtype : 'fieldset',
   title : 'Give proper Title',
   defaults: {
      anchor: '100%'
   },
   layout: 'anchor',
   collapsible: true,
   items: grid
}
});
```